# How to resolve a relationship to get a hold of the reference being pointed to?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have been creating a model where one of my assets have a reference to a specific participant.

When I retrieve my asset using the composer-client API I would like to retrieve the details of the participant being referenced.

In the [CTO language document](https://fabric-composer.github.io/reference/cto_language.html) I saw this sentence:
"Relationships must be resolved to retrieve an instance of the object being referenced. The act of resolution may result in null, if the object no longer exists or the information in the relationship is invalid."  but it does not describe how to do it.

Can someone please let me know what is the best way to resolve a relationship so that I can retrieve the instance of the object (in this case a participant) that  I am pointing to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can resolve relationships a couple of ways

Lets say we have an asset Widget that is defined as:

```
namespace SO

participant Person identified by email {
    o String email
}

asset Widget identified by assetId {
    o String email
    --> Person owner
}
```

1. Once you have a `Widget` asset, you can call `Widget.owner.getFullyQualifiedType()` which returns the name of the participant registry the `owner` is in. Then call `Widget.owner.getIdentifier()` to get the id of the `owner` in the `PersonRegistry`, then call `PersonRegistry.get(identifier)` to get the `owner` participant
2. When getting the `Widget` from the `WidgetRegistry`, you can call `WidgetRegistry.resolve(identifier)` to resolve all relationships